# Dynamdb issue with recognizing courses

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb

I'm suppose to create a table named Courses to hold attribute including Subject (e.g. SDEV), CatalogNbr (e.g. 400), Title (e.g. Secure Programming in the Cloud), NumCredits (e.g. 3), and a CourseID (e.g. 001). The CourseID should represent the Hash Key for the Courses table. Then provide a command line simple interface that allows a user to search for a title given the Subject and CatalogNbr. The search program should continue to loop until the user requests to exit. Also, if both Subject and CatalogNbr are not entered, the program should request the data be re-entered. My code is not recognizing the courses when they clearly exist. Apparently its somewhere within my search_title() part of the code and I can't figure it out.I've tried editing and adding the search_title() but to no avail.

[Screen shot of code not recognizing course](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sR4Ys.png)

**My full code is below:**

```
from __future__ import print_function

from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, And
import boto3
import sys

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table= dynamodb.Table('Courses')

def create_table():
    
        dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

        table = dynamodb.create_table(
        TableName='Courses',
        KeySchema=[
            {
                'AttributeName': 'subject',
                'KeyType': 'HASH'  #Partition key
            },
            {
                'AttributeName': 'catalognbr',
                'KeyType': 'RANGE'  #Sort key
            }
        ],
            AttributeDefinitions=[
            {
                'AttributeName': 'subject',
                'AttributeType': 'S'
            },
            {
                'AttributeName': 'catalognbr',
                'AttributeType': 'N'
            }enter image description here
        ],
        ProvisionedThroughput={
            'ReadCapacityUnits': 10,
            'WriteCapacityUnits': 10,
        }
    )

        print("Table status:", table.table_status)
    
def load_data():
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    
    courses = [[1, 'CMIS', '102', 'Inroduction to Problem Solving and Algorithm Design', '3'],
    [2, 'CMIS', '141', 'Inroductory Programming', '3'],
    [3, 'WRTG', '393', 'Advanced Technical Writing', '3'],
    [4, 'CMIS', '242', 'Intermediate Programming', '3'],
    [5, 'CMIS', '320', 'Relational Database Concepts and Applications', '3'],
    [6, 'SDEV', '300', 'Building Secure Python Applications', '3'],
    [7, 'SDEV', '350', 'Database Security', '3'],
    [8, 'SDEV', '360', 'Secure Software Engineering', '3'],
    [9, 'SDEV', '325', 'Detecting Software Vulnerabilities', '3'],
    [10, 'WRTG', '394', 'Advanced Business Writing', '3']]
    
    for course in courses:
        courseid = course[0]
        subject = course[1]
        catalognbr = course[2]
        title = course[3]
        numcredits = course[4]

        table.put_item(
           Item={
               'CourseID': courseid,
               'Subject': subject,
               'CatalogNbr': catalognbr,
               'Title': title,
               'NumCredits': numcredits,
            }
        )
        return courses
    
def get_subject():
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    subject = ['SDEV', 'WRTG', 'CMIS']
   
    while True:
      if subject == 'SDEV' or subject == 'WRTG' or subject == 'CMIS':
          return subject
       
def get_catalognbr():
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    catalognbr = ''
   
    while True:
       if catalognbr == '':
           return catalognbr
           
def search_title(subject, catalognbr):
    
        subject = subject.upper()
        catalognbr = catalognbr.upper()
    
        filters = {
            'Subject': subject,
            'CatalogNbr': catalognbr
        }
        response = table.scan(
        FilterExpression=And(*[(Key('CatalogNbr').eq(catalognbr)) or And('Subject').eq(subject) for key, value in filters.items()]))
 
        if not response['Count']:
            print('No course found with the given Subject and Catalog Number')
            return None
        else:
            return response['Items'][0]['title']

def run_search():
    
    subject = input('Enter the Subject: ')
    catalognbr = input('Enter the CatalogNbr: ')
    
    if not subject or not catalognbr:
        print('Both Subject and CatalogNbr are required')
        return False
        
    title = search_title(subject, catalognbr)
    
    if title:
        print(f'The title of {subject} {catalognbr} is {title}')
    return True

def main():
    while True:
        if not run_search():
            break
        if input('Would you like to search for another title? (Y or N)').upper() != 'Y':
            break
    print('Thanks for using the Catalog Search program.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Your partition key is: `subject`.

Your sort key is: `catalognbr`.

Your function parameters are therefore containing the items keys: `search_title(subject, catalognbr)`, which means you should do a `get_item` not a `Scan` with a filter:

```
def search_title(subject, catalognbr):
    res = table.get_item(
        Key={
            'subject': subject,
            'catalognbr': catalognbr
        }
    )
    return(res)


res = search_title('WRTG', '393')
```

If you do change your use case to non-key attributes then your FilterExpression should look like this:

`FilterExpression= reduce(And,([Key(key).eq(value) for key, value in filters.items()]))`